# Ubuntu Stuck At Boot Screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, reboot

I restarted ubuntu 20.04 as usual but this time at got stuck at the boot screen. I've been waiting for 20 minutes but nothing is happening.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Boot Screen Image:

[image: Boot Screen Image]

Comment: What is the "boot screen"? Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I've added an image. Please take a look. Yes, I've tried turning it on and off multiple times.

Comment: The only thing I see that might point to the problem is "GRUB failed boot detection".  I would work off of that.  What changes have you made to the PC lately?  New software, new OS, new hardware, etc? I don't think this happened spontaneously.  Try to figure out what could.have changed.

Comment: Give me a minute, I remember making a change to decrease shutdown time last I used the system, I get the information.

Comment: Here. I tried this when someone told to do this on reddit, https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/reduce-shutdown-time.html#:~:text=Delete%20the%20%23%20symbol%20and%20change,the%20default%20time%2090%20seconds.     But I changed decrease time from 90 to 4 sec

Comment: Is there anything we can do about it?

Comment: Hey, I think I figured out the error, I undid the part where I changed it so that it would take less time to shutdown, the article which I linked you, is strictly against stating the shutdown time less than 30 second and I had done 4 sec. Is there anything now that I fix this issue?

Comment: If anyone is still looking into this question, I had to reinstall ubuntu as that seemed to be the only answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this alteration alone would have caused the problem.  Did you make any other changes like this?  This, and any other change to the system configuration, should have been posted in your original question.

You can reverse manual alterations made to system files, assuming you either backed up the original, or you know exactly what you changed.

Luckily `/etc/systemd/system.conf` will also restore the default if you just delete it.   But I'd try to restore it first.

You will need to boot from installation media and choose the "Try Ubuntu" option so that you can access files, since you are no longer able to boot even to GRUB.

Once you are booted to the live session, you can make the changes you need to reverse any alterations you made to system files.

This should solve your problem.

I would advise against following advice from reddit and random blogs.  These are generally poor quality sources for information and advice.  Anything that involves manual alterations of system files should be met with skepticism and warrant a full understanding of the consequences before making any changes.

Comment: Thanks for the info but as I wrote in the comment I undid the the alteration I made using grub root command line, but that alone didn't fixed the issue, Is there any chance the data might be corrupted and is there is no hope to save it?

Comment: "grub root command line" - to what are you referring?  I thought GRUB would not boot? I'm fairly certain that the system will be read-only unless you actually make to to GRUB, and choose to start in recovery mode with networking.  I suggest to use a live session to revert the changes so they will be applied.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear. I'm on dual boot. I selected ubuntu as the OS on grub and when the ubuntu splash screen came the stuck there.I then tried to go into advanced ubuntu setting and then choose the recovery mode, where it gave me an option to gave me a root shell. I then changed the previous alterations I made using that shell. I thought that should've fixed it but it didn't. I'm now gonna try the method you told me(it took some time to make the live usb) and give you updates on that. Also, thank you very much for looking into this.

Comment: I'm in the live session now but I'm welcome into the new ubuntu session here and as I told you before the change I made using the grub are still here. I did but the error is still here. Also, is my only option left now is reinstall?

Comment: make the changes in the live session, then reboot!  If that still doesn't work you might need to look into the [`chroot` utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) which can allow you to act as the root user of the installed system even though you're working from another OS (the live session).  This is more of an advanced task.  An easier method might be to try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) - this also must be done from a live session.  If all fails, yeah, I'd probably start thinking about a reinstall.  The live session will let you rescue/backup

Comment: I'll into that. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Using Live boot, can you post the contents of systemd.conf, via copy/ paste to the question? Down to the line that you edited / fixed and maybe 3 or 4 lines past? I'd wait til all other options are exhausted before using boot repair. If it doesn't fix it, it will make it a lot harder to repair. Unless you are good w/ LVM2 volumes...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and, after many attempts, I managed to solve it as follows:

- During boot system, I was pressing ESC key to enter the advanced options of ubuntu (depending on the computer, it could be the f1, f2).
- I selected the option "Advanced options for Ubuntu".
- Then I selected one of the recovery mode options (one of them didn't work, so I tried again selecting the other one (which worked)).
- On the next screen, I selected the option to update GRUB and proceeded to normal Ubuntu boot.